# How can I highlight (mark) the active row in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

The conditional formatting does not help with that. I tried many scripts that are published online but non of them works.

Same issue is here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4469470?hl=en

Comment: Can I ask what you mean by `highlight`?

Comment: Mark or apply conditional formatting on the active row so that the user can focus on his location in the sheet crowded by data

Comment: Here is the same question but with better explanation: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4469470?hl=en

Comment: not possible...

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible to do.*

#### More Information:

The main reaason that thids can't be done is that the ***Sheets API nor Google Apps Script have listeners for when the active cell on a sheet changes.*** There are also no clicker or button press listeners, if the clicks or button presses ***do not make an edit or change to the Sheet.***

#### Testing & Reasoning:

I had a mess around with Apps Script to see if I could create some sort of workaround, though this ended up with encountering other obstacles.

There *is* a way of making the background of the active row change colour, which can be easily done in Apps Script with something like:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var currRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
sheet.getRange(currRow + ":" + currRow).setBackground("#F4C2C2");
```

Knowing this, and knowing that I couldn't call a trigger from just a click, I created a Sheets add-on instead with with a JavaScript function embedded in the  of the HTML document which calls the Apps Script method at a specific time-interval:

```html
<script>
    function poll() {
      setInterval(update, 500);
    }
    function update() {
      google.script.run.rowHighlighter();
    }
</script>
```

with the following `rowHighlighter()` function inside the `code.gs` file:

```js
function rowHighlighter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currRow = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();

  var l = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("currRow");
  if (l) {
    sheet.getRange(l + ":" + l).setBackground("#FFFFFF");  
  } 
  
  sheet.getRange(currRow + ":" + currRow).setBackground("#F4C2C2");
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperties({"currRow": currRow});
}
```

I thought it might be possible to call this function from within the sidebar of the Sheets add-on and use the `PropertiesService` class of Apps Script to store the currently selected row so that when clicked elsewhere the colour could be reset.

While this appeared to have positive results, this only lasted a few seconds - unfortunately after this the Apps Script quotas get hit and the errors in the console as seen from the Apps Script editor end show that some throttling is needed so not so many Apps Script requests are made. Of course, while this *is* something that you could do, increasing the interval at which the `update()` function is called in the add-on `<body>` reduced the real-timeness of the application and the whole functionality breaks.

In short; this can't be done. Both Apps Script and the Sheets API lack the functionality, and trying to build something that emulates it yourself will end in you using all your quota as the account limitations are hit.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [G Suite Developer - Extending Google Sheets with Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/sheets)
- [Google Apps Script - Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties)
- [Docs editors herlp - Highlight (or mark) the row the current cell is on](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/4469470?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
const range = e.range;
const sheet = range.getSheet();
const currRow = range.getRow()
const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
const maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
    
sheet.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, maxColumns).setFontWeight("normal");
sheet.getRange(currRow, 1, 1, maxColumns).setFontWeight("bold");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I got this to work here with a slight variation on highlighting, however, am needing the answer to: how do I limit it to rows>6 and stop highlighting at column 7   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R4GPipk9FyucRcKeXcosbKmXxUTGmuaoQDaUoVDVorU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Devendra Pathak's solution, how do we tell the script to not act on selections where it is the selected range is lower than row 5?  For example, click on A6, the script executes.  Click on A1, no changes, A6 remains highlighted.  Click on D7, the script executes.  Row 6 formatting becomes normal, and row 7 gets the special formatting.  As well, how does the script know to only format up to column 7?

Variation below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R4GPipk9FyucRcKeXcosbKmXxUTGmuaoQDaUoVDVorU/edit#gid=0

//Seeking: Act only when range is row 6 or higher

Answer (score -1):

Highlight row and column of cell where the mouse is clicked:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
 
sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();  
var formula = '=A1<>"1239"'; 
  
//---------------------------------------------------------------  
//RULE1  
var range1 = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, maxColumns);
var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
    .setBackground('lightgray')
    .setBold(true)
    .setRanges([range1])
    .build();
var rules1 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules1.push(rule1);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules1);
//--------------------------------------------------------------- 
//RULE2
var range2 = sheet.getRange(1, range.getColumn(), maxRows, 1);
var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
    .setBackground('lightgray')
    //.setBold(true)
    .setRanges([range2])
    .build();
var rules2 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules2.push(rule2);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules2);  
  
}
```

Comment: Please avoid remarks like *"it's not so hard"* - if it was not hard the OP wouldn't ask. Apparently for them it's hard and we are here to help them, not make them feel bad